# Software for drone navigation around buildings with 2D or 3D maps available?

Tags: quadcopters, dji, building

When you purchase and use a drone, such as a DJI AGRAS drone, you typically gain access to the DJI software (e.g., DJI SmartFarm App) that provides a bird's-eye view of the map.

I am looking for software that allows me to control a drone for objects like houses or buildings. Accordingly, the drone software should offer a map displaying the buildings in either 2D or, ideally, 3D.

The goal is to be able to fly the drone over the buildings. Is there software available that meets these requirements? If not, which SDK/programming language/IDE could I use to develop such an app?

Answer (score 1):

There are several types of software available for drone navigation around buildings with 2D or 3D maps. The most common type of software is the Autonomous Flight System (AFS). AFS is a type of software that uses advanced algorithms to create a map of the environment and then uses this map to autonomously navigate the drone. AFS can be used to navigate around buildings, as well as other obstacles such as trees and power lines.

Another type of software is the Visual Navigation System (VNS). VNS is a type of software that uses visual cues, such as landmarks, to help the drone navigate. VNS can be used to navigate around buildings and other obstacles, as well as to identify and avoid potential hazards.

The features of the software for drone navigation around buildings with 2D or 3D maps vary depending on the type of software. AFS typically includes features such as obstacle avoidance, path planning, and waypoint navigation. VNS typically includes features such as landmark recognition, route planning, and obstacle avoidance.

The advantages of using software for drone navigation around buildings with 2D or 3D maps include increased safety and efficiency. AFS and VNS both allow the drone to autonomously navigate around obstacles, which reduces the risk of collisions. Additionally, the use of maps allows for more efficient navigation, as the drone can plan the most efficient route to its destination.

The disadvantages of using software for drone navigation around buildings with 2D or 3D maps include the cost and complexity of the software. AFS and VNS can be expensive, and they require a significant amount of time and effort to set up and maintain. Additionally, the accuracy of the maps can be limited, as they may not be updated regularly or may not be detailed enough to accurately represent the environment.

Comment: Litchi will accept a surface model and allow you to maintain an altitude over that surface with along your pre-programmed flight path.  Depending  on your location you may have access to a free high-resolution LiDAR DSM to use as an input.